# How to show another navbar instead of dropdown menu using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Instead of having individual navbar items having dropdown lists can I have the list shown as another extra navbar just below it?

something like how apple does here 
http://www.apple.com/mac/

Comment: i don't get the exact question

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a Div underneath your primary menu and to insert your sub-menu items inside that child div.

Of course, the actual implementation depends on the actual use case, the goals of the aesthetic and the user experience.

You could do a JS onClick event that will trigger the child dive to be inserted when hovering on the parent, or do it in pure CSS with a:hover and changing display of the other div.

Since you are asking specifically Bootstrap, the simplest implementation would be for you to grab a Mega Menu and tweak it to fit your Use Case.

[YAMM](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/#) is very good, all you would need to do to achieve what you want is to set a grid to your sub-menu items whilst having the sub-menu wrapper match the parent nav width.

Of course, I would recommend you read the documentation and understand how it is implemented and try to come up with your own solution to fit your particular Use Case.